# Standard method of smoothing (amplitude envelope) of continuous wavelet transform

Tags: wavelet, smoothing, envelope

My basic question is, "What is the standard way to post-process/smooth a continuous wavelet transform result to measure the wavelet's activation at a specific frequency?"

When using wavelets for isolating a signal at a specific frequency, a continuous wavelet transform (CWT) may give the desired result. However, when using wavelets to measure the amount of energy at a specific frequency (i.e., in a way analogous to using a Fourier transform to transform the signal to the frequency domain), I think there needs to be a post-processing step after a CWT. For instance, the CWT of a sine wave with matching frequency will be another oscillating signal, rather than a high-valued DC signal. So, my question is, what is the typical way to “smooth” the result of a CWT to find the magnitude of the wavelet’s activation? I have had success using the magnitude of the Hilbert transform to extract an amplitude envelope after taking a CWT but haven’t seen others do this in the literature. An alternative could be a moving-window maximum. I would think this use case of CWT is common enough that there is a standard post-processing step.

Comment: Why not just take per-row (per-wavelet) energy? `sum(abs(cwt)**2, axis=-1)`. CWT is already smooth, but it's unclear what kind of "smoothness" you seek.

Comment: I still want to preserve temporal information. For instance, if the signal is a sine tone of 500 Hz that turn on/off every 0.1 seconds, the result should be close to a square wave with a period of 0.2 seconds.